# Files (nautilus) show files in Trash that not exists any more

Tags: permissions, nautilus, trash

My Files window (nautilus) in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS show some files in Trash folder and alert with not have sufficient permissions to delete message when I try delete them, and simultaneously in terminal

```
~/.local/share/Trash$ ls -lha  ~/.local/share/Trash/
total 8.0K
drwx------  2 myusername myusername 4.0K Nov 16 15:27 .
drwx------ 53 myusername myusername 4.0K Nov 16 15:21 ..
~/.local/share/Trash$
```

How I could solve this problem?

Comment: @guiverc 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: What are the files?   All I see there are the *pointers* that are used to know where you are on the file-system (ie. "." is the current $PWD, and ".." the pointer to the directory above that, you can use "cd .." for example to change to the directory above your current $PWD).  Those *pointers" ("." and "..") are the same one used in other OSes including windows)